# What is the difference between job scheduling and process scheduling?

Tags: operating-system, scheduling, cpu-architecture, job-scheduling

Is there any difference between job scheduler and process scheduler?

Comment: You use which definition of those?

Comment: The terminology can be different depending on the context. The textbook you're reading should define what a job is and what a process is. The Windows OS has also jobs and processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the terms are somewhat vague, there is a generally accepted usage of the words in question.

Process scheduling (or management) normally refers part of the operating system that shares CPU resources among the currently running programs (also called processes). The stress here is the fact that these programs are already running.

Job scheduling typically refers to programs that are to be run at a set time, typically (but not always) on a repetitive basis. This sort of thing if often done with a utility like cron. The emphasis here is that these programs are not currently running but are scheduled to run on some schedule.

In past (awful) times when batch operating systems were common, all programs were subject to this sort of job scheduling. Complex mainframe operating systems would determine which programs would be run and which would be delayed or rejected outright. Be glad, be very glad, that you do not need to learn the IBM Job Control Language (JCL) and may you be blessed by never having to.

Comment: Batch-like scheduling makes sense when the time scale for the value of the result is relatively large. Such can lead to greater system resource utilization. Amazon's AWS spot instances is practical example of the mutual benefit of job scheduling (cheap compute for the user, income from otherwise unused resources for the compute provider).

Comment: I've seen different modern textbooks on operating systems using the terms `job` and `process` differently. Sometimes, they are considered synonyms. So I'm not sure about how valid the statement `there is a generally accepted usage of the words` is. But I think that your answer is correct at least in the context of the 1950s-70s.

Comment: Thank you, Does a time-sharing operating systems have a job scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

"Job Scheduling" is normally used in the context of running batch jobs. This is an alien to concept to people who have only worked with Eunuchs variants. However, batch processing used to be an integral part of operating systems.

Typically, there were be batch queues with different attributes. A queue might limit the numbers of jobs that could run simultaneously. It could also only run during certain times during the day. The queues could have different priorities.

For example, if you had a molecular modeling job that would take two months to run, you might have it start running in the evening and stop in the morning.

The scheduling of jobs within queues is independent from the scheduling the process running on the system.